# A trouble with a custom editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am creating a custom `EditText` with a custom background. But it works wrongly. I created a line at the bottom of the view. And this line is animated. It works good. But if I start entering text, the line goes.

My Custom view:

```
public class DrawView extends EditText {

    private Paint paint;
    private Paint paintBefor;
    private float value;

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint();
        paintBefor = new Paint();
        value = 0.0f;
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paintBefor.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        paintBefor.setStrokeWidth(10);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawARGB(20, 102, 204, 255);
        int halfWidth = getWidth() / 2;
        canvas.drawLine(0,getHeight(),getWidth(),getHeight(), paintBefor);
        canvas.drawLine(halfWidth,getHeight(), halfWidth + value * halfWidth,getHeight(), paint);
        canvas.drawLine((1.0f - value) * halfWidth, getHeight(), halfWidth, getHeight(), paint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    public void startSkipAnimation() {
        ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener animatorUpdateListener = new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                setProgress((Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        };

        ValueAnimator progressAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f,1.0f);
        progressAnimator.addUpdateListener(animatorUpdateListener);
        progressAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        progressAnimator.setDuration(1500);
        progressAnimator.start();
    }

    private void setProgress(float value){
        this.value = value;
        invalidate();
    }

}
```

it looks like this:
[image]

But when I start to input text:
[image]

I want to keep the background line displayed when I am inputting text.

Comment: no need for extending `EditText`: just cal `setBackground(Drawable backgroun)` where backgroun is your custom Drawable

Comment: if you notice I use the animation bottom line

Comment: yes i noticed that of course, and whats the problem with `ValueAnimator` and custom `Drawable` class?

Comment: The problem is that I have two EditText. when i open fragment first editText start animation white line/ second edit text has line whits anoter color/ when i click second edit text, his line start animation and line of first editText change color to default. But now if i start input text my white line gone

Comment: and whats the problem with ValueAnimator and custom Drawable class?

Comment: video https://vk.com/video142681208_171148834 i want save baground